# НЕ получается сделать парсинг сайта

Tags: python

Я учусь парсингу , пытаюсь вывести название ссылку,название и описание первого фильма на странице
https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/

Но у меня просто название не получается вывести потому что постоянно эта ошибка:

```
 File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\PARSING.py", line 12, in <module>
    soup.find('div',class_='styles_root__ti07r').find('a',class_= 'base-movie-main-info_link__YwtP1').find('span',class_ = 'styles_mainTitle__IFQyZ styles_activeMovieTittle__kJdJj')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

вот код :

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/'

r = requests.get(url = url,headers = HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

soup.find('div',class_='styles_root__ti07r').find('a',class_= 'base-movie-main-info_link__YwtP1').find('span',class_ = 'styles_mainTitle__IFQyZ styles_activeMovieTittle__kJdJj')


print(soup)
```

ЕСЛИ МОЖНО МОЖЕТЕ ПОКАЗАТЬ НА ПРИМЕРЕ КАК ЗАПАРСИТЬ ДАННЫЕ ПЕРВОГО  ФИЛЬМА (ссылку ,названмие и инфу) пж

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/'
r = requests.get(url = url,headers = HEADERS)
print(r.url)

https://www.kinopoisk.ru/showcaptcha?cc=1&retpath=https%3A//www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250%3F_c6aa2f0034c04233ad7f28726b2d39d5&t=2/1653893578/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&u=4f5c4274-3c791ba6-9d237261-b16551c9&s=8af38ee229f7796075cf16d1ce2292d
```

Кинопоиск не любит ботов

Comment: Спасибо  а можете Объяснить  как вы изменили ссылку и как это помогло чтобы на других сайтах мог делать  подобное

Comment: 'как вы изменили ссылку' я не чего не менял.

Comment: Ой извините  а что это в самом конце

Comment: заходили на 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/' произошла переадрисация на капчу (потому что бот по версии кинопоиска).

Comment: И что теперь  делать ?

Comment: Если не знаете как прикинутся браузером с помощью requests, используйте библиотеку Selenium